# CircularBufferDataProvider addSample NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, nebula

I sometimes (few times on a plot stretching 3-minutes with points added every 100ms or so) receive a `NullPointerException`, but I do not see any possible cause.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.nebula.visualization.xygraph.dataprovider.CircularBufferDataProvider.fireDataChange(CircularBufferDataProvider.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.nebula.visualization.xygraph.dataprovider.CircularBufferDataProvider.addSample(CircularBufferDataProvider.java:155)
    at myProject.XYGraphTransfer.addPoint(XYGraphTransfer.java:432)
```

Here is the code sample.

```
trace1Provider = new CircularBufferDataProvider(true);
trace1Provider.setBufferSize(XYGraphTransfer.Graph_BufferEntries);
trace1Provider.setUpdateDelay(100);
Trace trace1 = new Trace("Time Plot", xyGraph.primaryXAxis, xyGraph.primaryYAxis, trace1Provider);
...
Long timeCurrent = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
Sample oSample = new Sample(timeCurrent, valueBase);
trace1Provider.addSample(oSample);
```

The exception is always on the `trace1Provider.addSample(oSample)` line.

`oSample` can never be `null`, so that possibility is out.

A clue is the actual error line,

```
at org.eclipse.nebula.visualization.xygraph.dataprovider.CircularBufferDataProvider.fireDataChange(CircularBufferDataProvider.java:474)
```

That does not help me very much, because fire the [source](http://git.eclipse.org/c/nebula/org.eclipse.nebula.git/plain/widgets/visualization/org.eclipse.nebula.visualization.xygraph/src/org/eclipse/nebula/visualization/xygraph/dataprovider/CircularBufferDataProvider.java) for `fireDataChange()` does not say very much. The `innerUpdate()` function, merely sets a dirty flag. As the crash is in `flagDataChange()` and not somewhere else, there is no really down stream cause. The other two calls, `fireUpdate()` and `super.fireDataChange()`, one can sort of eliminate, because if `FireUpdate()` or a method downstream of that was the cause, then Eclipse would mention that function, not `fireDataChange()` in the `CircularBufferDataProvider` class.

```
@Override
protected synchronized void fireDataChange()
{
    if (updateDelay > 0)
    {
        innerUpdate();
        if (!duringDelay)
        {
            Display.getCurrent().timerExec(updateDelay, fireUpdate);
            duringDelay = true;
        }
    } else
        super.fireDataChange();
}

@Override
protected void innerUpdate()
{
    dataRangedirty = true;
}
```

My thought is some sort of contention, but there is only one function that adds points to the graph and that is in the application thread. The graph exists on the application thread too.

UPDATE:
Full stack trace.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.nebula.visualization.xygraph.dataprovider.CircularBufferDataProvider.fireDataChange(CircularBufferDataProvider.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.nebula.visualization.xygraph.dataprovider.CircularBufferDataProvider.addSample(CircularBufferDataProvider.java:155)
    at prjNetAccelerator.XYGraphTransfer.addPoint(XYGraphTransfer.java:432)
    at prjNetAccelerator.AppGraphTransfer.addPoint(AppGraphTransfer.java:283)
    at prjNetAccelerator.AppGraphTransfer.pushPoint(AppGraphTransfer.java:187)
    at prjNetAccelerator.HtsLink.getStatusGui(HtsLink.java:456)
    at prjNetAccelerator.HtsLink.getStatusBasic(HtsLink.java:568)
    at prjNetAccelerator.ToolsTreeFolders.fetchFiles(ToolsTreeFolders.java:1351)
    at prjNetAccelerator.TimerFilesFetch.run(TimerFilesFetch.java:81)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: `Display.getCurrent()` - can that ever return null? eg transiently, if the Display is changing?

Comment: Might this be relevant? https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_get_a_Display_instance%3F

Comment: @AndyTurner That is a good thought. I saw that and immediately dismissed Display.getCurrent() returning NULL, but you are right. What else? I thought how is it possible that the current display ever returns null. I would effect a change in that code to put a test, but Nebula does not belong to me.

Comment: @AndyTurner Your second comment with the link might be spot on. I will update my question with the complete trace. This one particular call is from a timer, which is another thread that might not have a display. My only hesitation is that all points are from the same place, or so I think.

Comment: I added a line before the actual call and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

@AndyTurner was right about the display being the issue.

I changed the code to the following, ran quite a few tests, and that prevented the exceptions.

```
if (null != Display.getCurrent())
    trace1Provider.addSample(oSample);
```

I will have to investigate the null display issue.

Comment: `Display.getCurrent()` returns null on every thread except the User Interface thread. Use `Display.getDefault()` to get the display on any thread.

Comment: Thank you. I learned something, however the bug is in the Nebula code. The development team coded this function WITHOUT doing a check for null and without using Display.getDefault(), thereby setting up a NULL pointer exception. The fix must be in their code, otherwise others will suffer.

Comment: It looks like it is intended that `CircularBufferDataProvider.addSample` should only be called from the User Interface thread and you are calling it from a timer thread. You could wrap the call in a `Display.getDefault().syncExec` runnable so that it does run in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the same problem with the current version (2.1.0.201808161734) while trying to update the dataprovider from a separate Observer class. What worked for me is to get the display from the Composite where the widget is in and wrap the timerExec in asyncExec:

```
MyCircularBufferDataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider {...

    @Override
    protected synchronized void fireDataChange() {
        if (updateDelay > 0) {
            if (!duringDelay) {
                parentComposite.getDisplay().asyncExec(
                        ()-> parentComposite.getDisplay().timerExec(updateDelay, fireUpdate));
                duringDelay = true;
            }
        } else
            super.fireDataChange();
    }
}
```